# How can I reduce padding after figure?

Tags: spacing, floats

```
\documentclass{mwrep}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
I use figures with captions.

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{foo}

First paragraph (previous).

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics{a.jpg}
  \caption{Opis}
\end{figure}

Second paragraph (following).

\end{document}
```

How can I change vertical space (padding?) between caption and following paragraph?
Also, I want to change (increase a little) space between previous paragraph and top of image.

Comment: I recommend using more than just [h] for positioning. See [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned/2282#2282).

Comment: `[!htbp]` puts image on the center of new page and I don't want that. `[h]` puts image at the same place as in source code and if it doesn't fit, at the top of next page. I like this behaviour. Why should I change that?

Comment: In that case use `[ht]`.

Comment: OK, thank you :). Can you give me example when edding this `t` would be necessary? In my document it doesn't change anything but I believe at some cases it will be helpful :).

Comment: If you only allow `h`, you might get an overfull page if there's not enough space left. LaTeX is clever enough to change to `ht` for you, but it's better to write `ht` since you mean `ht`. See also [`h` float specifier changed to `ht` warning when not attempting to specify a float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You could change `\belowcaptionskip`, for example:

```
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
```

For further customizations I recommend using the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. It provides a lot of features and is very well documented. If you're using the caption package, you can set the spacing as:

```
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}
```

Comment: Thanks to yours and Mikael's answer I was able to set caption spacing to my needs. But still I don't know how can I increase space between paragraph and figure that is below it.

Comment: You can raise the length `\intextsep` by `\addtolength` or `\setlength`.

Comment: Where should this command go? Inside the figure environment?

Comment: Yes. You can place it right before the `\caption{}` line. For eg: 
`\begin{figure}
 \centering\includegraphics[]{my_figure.png}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-8pt}
    \caption{my_caption}
   \label{my_label}
\end{figure}`

Comment: I'm getting `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \belowcaptionskip` Do I need to include some package?

Comment: How can I apply this setting to just one figure? The above solution seems to affect all figures.

Answer (score 127):

You can modify the following lengths, which affect all floats.;

- `\floatsep`: space left between floats (12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt).
- `\textfloatsep`: space between last top float or first bottom float and the text (20.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt).
- `\intextsep` : space left on top and bottom of an in-text float (12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt).
- `\dbltextfloatsep` is \textfloatsep for 2 column output (20.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt).
- `\dblfloatsep` is \floatsep for 2 column output (12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt).
- `\abovecaptionskip`: space above caption (10.0pt).
- `\belowcaptionskip`: space below caption (0.0pt).

[Source](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html)

Comment: +1, but it would be handy if you added the default values of these lengths to your answer.

Comment: @lockstep: Done, (at least for article class).

Comment: `\addtolength{\textfloatsep}{-0.2in}` is the correct answer as you rightfully mentioned.

Comment: That's the answer! just for pure beginner like me, to use them put `\setlength{\textfloatsep}{2.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt}` before `\begin{document}` will take effect. Plus, for two column document, if the figure cross two columns (`\begin{figure*}[!t]`), `\dbltextfloatsep` works. For figure fit in single column (`\begin{figure}[h!]`), `\intextsep` works. For figures fit in single column but stick at the bottom (`\begin{figure}[b!]`), `\textfloatsep` works.