# Vertical space after table on top of a page with text continuing from last page

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs

How can I remove the spacing after a table that appears on top of page 2, when I have a paragraph that starts from page 1 and continues on to page 2? I can't use `\vspace` since that just moves the whole paragraph on page 1.

Comment: Please prepare a minimal working example so  we can reproduce what you see.

Comment: it is very hard to tell with so little information but the space between top floats and text on the page is `\textfloatsep` so you can set that with `\setlength` in the document preamble.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [How can I reduce padding after figure?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23313/5764)

Comment: @Werner your suggestion did the trick. I used \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt} to get rid of spacing