# Removing new line after figure

Tags: floats

We've been given a template to work with. I am adding figures with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Figures/System/reinf-learning.jpg}
      \caption{Components of a reinforcement learning agent}
      \label{fig:reinf-learning}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, there is always a new line between after the figure. I'm trying to find something that will allow me to remove this new line. How can this be done? Thanks.

I've tried adding `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}` but to no avail.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23313/156344

Comment: @JouleV I've tried the accepted solution, but it doesn't seem to affect anything in my case.

Comment: Replace the `center` environment by the `\centering` command. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/134144)