# How to keep my default floating environment spacing before them, while reducing my figures spacing after they?

Tags: spacing, floats

I am using `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}` from [How can I reduce padding after figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23313/how-can-i-reduce-padding-after-figure)  to reduce the spacing **after** my figures. And it is working fine.

But it is also affecting my new floats environments and reducing to almost `0` the spacing **before** the environment.

How can I fix my floats environments spacing before (keep their spacing) while keeping by figure environments reduced spacing after the figure?
[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption,newfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\listofquadrosname{List of Frames}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},name=Frame,
within=chapter,listname=\listofquadrosname]{quadro}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
\begin{document}
Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{latex.png}
    \caption{Opis}
\end{figure}

After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After.

Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before.

\begin{quadro}[h]
\caption{Stuff.}
Contents.
\end{quadro}

After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the caption package to control caption spacing above and below and instruct it that for quadros captions go above, thus inverse spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be just to use the `\vspace` command e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption,newfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\listofquadrosname{List of Frames}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},name=Frame,
within=chapter,listname=\listofquadrosname]{quadro}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
\begin{document}
    Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before.

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption{Opis}
    \end{figure}

    After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After.

    Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before.

    \vspace{5mm} % Increase the spacing before the enviroment
    \begin{quadro}[h]
        \caption{Stuff.}
        Contents.
    \end{quadro}

    After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry this is really bad advice. `quadro` is a float so may be moved to help with page breaking, but the vspace would stay in that place forcing a space between the two paragraphs in the main document flow.

Answer (score 1):

After reading:

1. [How to disable paragraphs inside my environment with \let\par\relax?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388369/how-to-disable-paragraphs-inside-my-environment-with-let-par-relax)
2. [Please tutor the usage of patchcmd and xpatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/please-tutor-the-usage-of-patchcmd-and-xpatch)

I managed to fix this by directly patching the `figure` environment, leaving all other environments intact:

```
\xpretocmd{\figure}{\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}}{}{}
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption,newfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\listofquadrosname{List of Frames}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},name=Frame,
within=chapter,listname=\listofquadrosname]{quadro}

\xpretocmd{\figure}{\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}}{}{}

\begin{document}
Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{latex.png}
    \caption{Opis}
\end{figure}

After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After.

Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before. Before.

\begin{quadro}[h]
\caption{Stuff.}
Contents.
\end{quadro}

After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After. After.
\end{document}
```

[image]