# How do I reduce the space between the caption of the image and normal text?

Tags: floats, multicol

I am using the osameet3 package and am working with multicol. The image will only import if i use \begin{figure}[H], however this is causing strange extra space between the caption and the rest of my text.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` --- no more than 2 pages and a figure using `lipsum` for text filling. Where is the `osameet3` package (class?) ? In general it is not a good idea to use the `[H]` positioning option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post helps you: [How can I reduce padding after figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23313/how-can-i-reduce-padding-after-figure)

Another idea i have, but it is less elegant: \vspace{-20px}

Comment: Would this go under the image ?

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work. i adjusted all the way to -130 and it made no difference and if i go larger then it overlaps images and texts.

Comment: `px` usually refers to the resolution of a screen.  It is not one of the dimension units recognized by (La)TeX.  `pt` would be more appropriate, or some multiple of a derivative unit, e,g,, `-1.5\baselineskip`.  (It would go within the `figure` environment, just before the end.)