# How to remove extra space at the bottom of tables and figures?

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, vspace

As shown below, tables and figures seem to add extra space at the bottom:

[image]

In the example below the problem persist also using `float` (`\intextsep` was multiplied by 1.5 `\baselineskip` for better readability):

[image]

Code for the first image:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{c} 
  \hline
  table \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

\begin{table}[h]
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
 \begin{tabular}{c} 
  \hline
  table \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\end{table}

\noindent CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \includegraphics{demo}
\end{figure}

\noindent DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
 \includegraphics{demo}
 \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\end{figure}

\noindent EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23316/197451

Comment: @jsbibra already tried, no change except for \intextsep, which modifies both

Comment: your question isn't very clear you say "seem to add extra space" but you answer this in your own question, latex (for `h` position) adds `\intextsep` before and after the float.

Comment: if you want no space, do not want the float to move and have no captions, you can simply remove the `figure` and `table` environments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the code I posted is a MWE to reproduce the issue, the final look will be the one in the second picture. My question is why the bottom space is different from the top one, you can see that along `\intextsep` something else is adding space. Even after removing the two `\intextsep` there is a bit of space left under the figures/tables

Comment: sorry your example doesn't set intextsep or remove it?, if intextsep is 0 latex adds no space although  the standard \baselineskip or \lineskip spaces will be added as for any content. You don't supply code for the second image, I assume your FONTE text is from \caption? but it is hard to comment on that at all. perhaps \caption is adding space below (there is a standard `\belowcaptionskip`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my code refers to the first image because I would like people to focus on it. The second image is only a proof that the extra bottom space is somehow linked to `\intextsep`. However, setting it to zero makes everything a mess, you get overlapping lines if you try. My goal is fixing the issue for the first image, and then apply the change to the second one myself. Caption doesn't add any extra space below it by default, and I can't fix it with negative `\belowcaptionskip`, that's why I posted a MWE without `\caption`, in order to focus on less code.

Comment: you would not normally get overlapping lines with intextsep=0pt, obviously your example code produces overlapping as it inserts negative space. If you don't insert negative space and set intextsep to 0pt latex macros insert no extra space so you are probably just seeing \lineskip which is 1pt by default. I would try to post an answer but I am really still not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the space around here floats to 0pt and remove the negative spacing added in the example you get

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

\noindent AA

\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{c} 
  \hline
  table \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent BB

\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{c} 
  \hline
  table \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent CC

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \includegraphics{demo}
\end{figure}

\noindent DD

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \includegraphics{demo}
\end{figure}

\noindent EE

\end{document}
```

looking in the log you see the vertical space after the first table before BB is

```
...\penalty 0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus -1.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.3
```

so standard baselineskip spacing as between lines of a paragraph, similarly before CC

```
....\glue 0.0
...\penalty 0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus -1.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.3
```

DD and EE are the same.

Comment: I see, but how can I remove the vertical space between the first table and BB? Is there a `\vspace` lenght or similar I can enter within the table/figure environment to get rid of it and have a symmetical top/bottom spacing?

Comment: @Polizi8 sorry I just do not understand. As I showed it is just baselineskip, so if the table ended with a row of letters with descenders like gygygygyggy and the BBB were capitals, or even accented capitals, they would over-print if you put them any closer together. It is exactly the same as asking about the space between lines of a paragraph, if you use all lowercase letter with no descenders it looks like there is extra space.

Comment: @Polizi8 If you _really_ want that you can use `\nointerlineskip
\noindent BB`

Comment: Thank you, so the small space in the first picture it was that kind of skip. I fixed the issue in my second image by adding `\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}` before closing the environment. Now I can freely set `\intextsep` to what I want to regulate the same space before and after a table/figure