# `h' float specifier changed to `ht'

Tags: math-mode, floats, warnings

When I add this text:

```
The pdpotri routine computes the inverse of a real symmetric or complex Hermitian positive definite distributed matrix $sub(A) = A(ia:ia+n-1, ja:ja+n-1)$ using the Cholesky factorization $sub(A) = UH*U or sub(A) = L*LH$ computed by pdpotrf.
```

to my .tex, I get this:

```
LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.
```

If I remove it, it goes away. If I remove only the match mode (the dollar signs), the warning is still alive. The document has sections and subsections, if that helps. It also has many math inside it. I am trying to produce a minor example...

How to get rid of this warning?

---

*EDIT*

Check first comment of Gonzalo!

Comment: Easy. Never use `[h]` as float placement specifier. It is such a recipe for disaster that internally is changed to the less restrictive , but no much better, `[ht]`. By the way, the text you mention in your question has nothing to do with the warning; the warning come from using `[h]` as float placement specifier.

Comment: Bellissimo @GonzaloMedina. I had two `[h]` specifiers in two tables. Should I delete my question, or you think it would be nice to answer? I couldn't find a solution on my own..

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before, e.g. [\`h' float specifier changed to \`ht' warning when not attempting to specify a float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1511)

Comment: @gsamaras, you should allow to LaTeX more freedom to placing a floats. Instead of `[h]` write `[htb]` or put in preamble `\def\fps@figure{hbtp}` and `\def\fps@table{hbtp}`, of course beteen `makeatletter` and `makeatother˙`.

Comment: No @TorbjørnT., I had seen this question long ago and did again, but I couldn't find the connection. To an *experienced* user, the connection might be obvious. I will keep that in mind Zarko, thanks!

Comment: @gsamaras I think we could close it as duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1511/3954 (which  Torbjørn T. found). Do you agree?

Comment: OK @GonzaloMedina, good balanced idea. I will place an edit to highlight your first comment here, do not delete that comment please. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- the answer there doesn't actually say *why* the change from `[h]` to `[ht]` happened, relevant to the present question.  the reason here is that the addition of text was enough to make the float no longer fit on the specified page.  adding that information to the answer in the question you suggest would take care of that confusion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ah, yes. That is the reason and the last part of my first comment is misleading. Would you like to add that info to the other answer?

Comment: Just an idea. Can she answer my question and also mark it as a duplicate? @GonzaloMedina

Comment: I think it's better if the additional information mentioned by @barbarabeeton in his comment is added as an editt to the other answer.

Comment: You are the experienced people here, you know. :) Thanks again.