# missing $ error when creating a table

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am going to create a table using the following commands. I use the `xepersian` package.

```
\begin{latin}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c c c|} 
 \hline
 p & q & \varphi_q^p(x)\\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline
 p & -1 & ‎\vert‎ x \vert^p \\ 
 2 & 0 & ln(x^2+1) \\
 2 & -0.5 & 2 ‎\sqrt{x^2+1}-2‎ \\
 2 & 1 & ‎\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}‎ \\
 1 & 1 & ‎\frac{‎\vert‎ x ‎\vert‎}{\vert x \vert +1}‎ \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{latin}
```

Although I used the `latin` environment I got the error of missing `$`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the amsmath package for formulas and enclosing them properly, ie $formula$, will remove the error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{latin}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c c c|} 
 \hline
 p & q & $\varphi_q^p(x)$ \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline
 p & -1 & ‎$\vert‎ x \vert^p$ \\ 
 2 & 0 & $\ln(x^2+1)$ \\
 2 & -0.5 & $2 ‎\sqrt{x^2+1}-2‎$ \\
 2 & 1 & ‎$\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}‎$ \\
 1 & 1 & ‎$\frac{‎\vert‎ x ‎\vert‎}{\vert x \vert +1}‎$ \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{latin}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Leucippus implies, subscripts (`_{}`), superscripts (`^{}`), `\frac`, `\sqrt`, `\ln`, `\vert` are commands that can only be used in math mode, so you need to enclose them in dollar signs or `\( ... \)`.  As such he has answered your question, this answer is just a suggestion for an alternative way of typesetting that table.

Changes:

- I've added the `array` package, and used `*{3}{>{$}c<{$}}` as the column specification for the table. This will create three `c` columns (`*{3}`) where a `$` is inserted at the start (`>{$}`) and end (`<{$}`) of each cell, effectively setting all cells in math mode.
- I've loaded `booktabs` and used `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline`, while removing vertical rules. A lot of people prefer this style of tables, see for example the manual of `booktabs`.
- `mathtools` provides `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, with which I've defined the `\abs` macro to set the absolute values.

Additional note:

- Often when using `[h!]` as a float specifier, you will get a warning saying  `` `h' specifier changed to `ht' ``. This is because there is no room for the table exactly where you put it, so `h` is not an option. Therefore it is recommend to use at least `ht` as float specifiers, thereby giving LaTeX some more freedom as to where the float should be placed. See for example [`h' float specifier changed to `ht' warning when not attempting to specify a float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/h-float-specifier-changed-to-ht-warning-when-not-attempting-to-specify-a-flo)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{$}c<{$}}} 
\toprule
 p & q & \varphi_q^p(x) \\ [0.5ex] 
\midrule
 p & -1 & ‎\abs{x}^p \\ 
 2 & 0 & \ln(x^2+1) \\
 2 & -0.5 & 2 ‎\sqrt{x^2+1}-2‎ \\
 2 & 1 & ‎\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}‎ \\
 1 & 1 & ‎\frac{‎\abs{x}}{\abs{x}+1}‎ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```