# Why is my figure's caption floating?

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, vertical-alignment

[image]

Not only my figure is flipped, the caption is floating at the top overlapping my picture. Why did this happen?

```
\graphicspath{{picture/}}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{proloquoScreenshot1.jpeg}\\
    \caption{Proloquo Screenshot 1}
    \label{fig:proloquoScreenshot1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Without seeing more, I can only guess: This looks like the JPEG file is corrupted. The caption is placed correctly with respect to the bottom of the figure (which happens to be at the top). This is quite a standard behaviour of the `graphicx` package.

Comment: hmm okayokay i'll go change the picture.. thankss.. @yo'

Comment: A couple of unrelated notes: 1) Using `[h]` as the float specifier will often give you a warning that [`h float specifier changed to ht`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1511). As such it is usually best to not have only `h`. 2) The ```\\``` after `\includegraphics` is unnecessary, captions are usually set in a separate paragraph anyway.

Comment: thanks @TorbjørnT. .. i knot what the \\ is unnecessary.. i forgot to delete it because i was trying if it works or not because my image is flipped.. and all the while i've been using [h] all the time haha but thanks for the info :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is caused by a corrupt image file.