# Pgfplots/Tikz figure not centering

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, horizontal-alignment

I have the following graph and I have no idea why it is not centering.

[image: example]

Here is the code as a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[]{thesis}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % folder


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar, 
    y = 1.2cm,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 }, 
    hide x axis, 
    tickwidth = 0pt,
    xmin=0, 
    xlabel={Percentage \%},
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    bar width=15pt,
    symbolic y coords={%
        {Drunken driving},
        {Unadjusted speed},
        {Insufficient safety distance},
        {Not respecting right of way},
        {Turning, U-turn, reversing, entering the flow of traffic, starting off the edge of the road}},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ytick=data,yticklabel style={text width=10cm,align=right,font=\linespread{1.2}\selectfont},
    ]
    \addplot[style={blue,fill=blue,mark=none}] coordinates {
        (3,{Drunken driving})
        (10.7,{Unadjusted speed})
        (15.9,{Insufficient safety distance}) 
        (17.3,{Not respecting right of way}) 
        (19,{Turning, U-turn, reversing, entering the flow of traffic, starting off the edge of the road})
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Causes of accidents with personal injuries caused by human error in Germany in 2018.}
    \label{fig:accidents}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom `thesis` documentclass, or the one available in MikTeX?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm using a custom one from my university. The `thesis` is just for the example.

Comment: It would be better to use a standard class such as `report` or `article` then.

Comment: As far as I can see my first comment was correct, the additional whitespace seems to come from the `text width` in the `yticklabel style`. Try adding `draw` to the `yticklabel style` as well, then you'll see the outline of those nodes.

Comment: Try adding `scale only axis,width=0.45\textwidth` to the `axis` options, and use `text width=0.45\textwidth` in the `yticklabel style`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Would you perhaps also know why the y axis text is not perfectly aligned to tbe bar's center? The text is slightly too high I believe. I can make a separate question if it's not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I first suspected, it is caused by the `text width` setting the `yticklabel style`, which makes those nodes very wide. One way of avoiding guesswork for appropriate widths is to add `scale only axis,width=0.45\textwidth` to the `axis` options, and use `text width=0.45\textwidth` in the `yticklabel style`.

Regarding the small misalignment, it is because of the text height and text depth. A quick fix is to add `\strut` to the `font` key for the `yticklabel style`.

```
\documentclass{report}

% this is added just for example, to make textblock of similar width to that in screenshot
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht] % having h as the only placement specifier can lead to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1511
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar, 
    y = 1.2cm,
    scale only axis,width=0.45\textwidth, % <-- added
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 }, 
    hide x axis, 
    tickwidth = 0pt,
    xmin=0, 
    xlabel={Percentage \%},
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    bar width=15pt,
    symbolic y coords={%
        {Drunken driving},
        {Unadjusted speed},
        {Insufficient safety distance},
        {Not respecting right of way},
        {Turning, U-turn, reversing, entering the flow of traffic, starting off the edge of the road}},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ytick=data,
    yticklabel style={
%      draw, % can be  useful for debugging
      text width=0.45\textwidth, % <-- added
      align=right,
      font=\linespread{1.2}\selectfont\strut % <-- added \strut
    }
    ]
    \addplot[style={blue,fill=blue,mark=none}] coordinates {
        (3,{Drunken driving})
        (10.7,{Unadjusted speed})
        (15.9,{Insufficient safety distance}) 
        (17.3,{Not respecting right of way}) 
        (19,{Turning, U-turn, reversing, entering the flow of traffic, starting off the edge of the road})
    };
    \end{axis}
% shows bounding box of tikzpicture, can also be useful for debugging
% \draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Causes of accidents with personal injuries caused by human error in Germany in 2018.}
    \label{fig:accidents}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]